# Objective-C – Message a view controller from application delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to download some data in the application delegate in `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

After I have downloaded some data I want to set this data to an `NSArray` property in a view controller. If I have a synthesized property of NSArray (nonatomic, retain) called `data` I would like to do `[viewController setData:downloadedData];`

How would I call the active viewController instance from the application delegate?

My application structure is a Tab Bar Controller as root controller.

Comment: What's your application structure? (do you have navigation controller, tab controller)? Also NSNotification may be useful in this scenario...

Comment: I'm using a Tab Bar controller...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `NSNotificationCenter` which will essentially broadcast a message to all objects that have subscribed to that particular message.

In your view controller subscribe to the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(downloadedData:) 
    notificationName:@"DownloadedData" 
    object:data];

- downloadedData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.data = notification.object;
}
```

And in your app delegate send the notification to the subscribers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"DownloadedData" 
    object:data];
```

Comment: Don't forget to stop the controller from observing the notification name with `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removerObserver:self];`.

Comment: Yes, if you don't put that in your `dealloc` method, your object won't release and will leak memory.

Comment: Why is this method preferred over using a setter for the instantiated view controller?

Comment: It gets messy. You will end up constructing the view controller in your app delegate and then calling your app delegate from your view controller to set the property and then calling your view controller from your app delegate. Reminds me of a dog chasing it's tail. You can also observe that notification from other objects if you want to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "calling your app delegate from your view controller to set the property". I was thinking of calling the setter of the view controller in the app delegate. Anyhow, just for the kicks out of it, how would I call the view controller from my app delegate if I wanted to?

Comment: One other thing is that you will probably get warnings if you call custom setters on the app delegate since you can import the app delegate in the view controller or you will get a circular reference.

Comment: Just synthesize a property for the view controller in the app delegate and call `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setMyViewController:self];` if you named the property `myViewcontroller`

Comment: So if I want a reference to my view controller in app delegate I have to set the reference from the view controller? I can not set the reference to the view controller from the app delegate? Also what do you think of the @umair answer below of using a delegate vs your with NSNotificationCenter?

Answer (score 1):

Add delegateComplete property in your app delegate class:

```
//define ivar
id delegateComplete;

//define property
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegateComplete;

//synthesize
@synthesize delegateComplete;
```

In init method or viewDidLoad of your viewController do following:

```
MainClass *appDelegate = (MainClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.delegateComplete = self;
```

replace MainClass with your app class. After downloading is complete, do following in your app delegate:

```
[delegateComplete loadingCompletedWithData:data];
```

Dont forget to add this method in your viewController:

```
- (void)loadingCompletedWithData:(NSData *)data
```

What happens is that your view controller registers to your app delegate. When loading completes, if your view controller has registered, call loadingCompletedWithData. Proper way of doing this would be through a protocol.

Comment: In addition to this anser: don't forget to import your view controller in the app delegate.